# Why does the python JSON module show the error : json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I have a problem with the JSON module. I can't find out why this is an error:

```
with open('Book Store Data','r+') as file:
    print(json.load(file))
    json_contents = json.load(file)
```

I can't figure out why the 3rd line shows the error : **json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**
but printing it is fine. The file I am reading is just a test:

```
[{"name": "George", "degree": "Coding"}, {"name": "Connor", "degree": "Science"}]
```

Comment: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` will stop your code. End of. You're not showing something. "but printing it is fine"

Comment: You have a list of jsons, not a json in the file. This won't be read, you should use readlines() and try processing it.

Comment: Why would it work printing then, but not assigning to a variable? I should also add that putting the whole list in a JSON doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reached the end of the file by calling `json.load` the first time. Assign it to a variable first, then print it. Otherwise, call `file.seek(0)`  in between calls to `json.load`

Comment: Thanks! I was having an error before I added the print statement, but I must've fixed that error since I added the print, and then the print made another error!